# Removing stop words in one file from another file

Tags: bash

I have a file File1.txt which has some words. I have another file (called  blacklistwords.txt) and I need to remove all the words contained in the blacklistwords.txt from the original file1.txt.

```
File1.txt
----------
return  25
murder  28
another  54
stackoverflow  12
response  16
violence  32


blacklistwords.txt
------------------
violence
murder
crime
```

This is how the output should look like:

```
Final output:
-------------
return  25
another  54
stackoverflow  12
response  16
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what OS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this  and it worked:

```
grep -i -F -v -f blacklistwords.txt file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is basically correct.

Let me just note that you did not ask for case-insensitivite matching, and adding it via the `-i` switch imposes quite a big performance penalty, at least for unicode environments, so you might want to strip that if it's not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

While breaking down user965692's solution for my own case, I found the need for another option, `-w`, which only searches whole words.

To break it down fully:

- `-i` tells grep to ignore case
- `-F` tells grep to expect a list of fixed strings
- `-w` searches whole words (i.e., if "flow" was a stopword, it would not match "overflow"
- `-v` inverts the matches (i.e., only print what is *not* in the list of strings
- `-f blacklistwords.txt` obtains the patterns from the lines of the given file

Hence, to remove all of the blacklisted words:

`grep -i -F -w -v -f blacklistwords.txt file1.txt`